# Workflow job without the trigger in the name?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow/job, let's name it `Checker`. The job checks some conditions on PRs for my repo.

There are 2 types of events that I care about (because they might change the results of the job). These are `pull_request` events and `pull_request_review` events.

So in my workflow YAML I specify both types of events as triggers for my `Checker` job.

My issue is the GitHub UI will put the event name in the job name, and I cannot find a way to stop GitHub from doing this. So on my PR if both events occur then it will appear like 2 separate job runs:

- `Checker (pull_request)` - failed 2 hours ago
- `Checker (pull_request_review)` - passed 5 minutes ago

And the GitHub UI for rulesets only allows me to specify just the job name `Checker` as a required PR check.

So if the `Checker` job fails on the `pull_request` event but later passes after the `pull_request_review` event then GitHub still considers the check failed and will not allow the PR to merge. But for my use case, if the later event passes then I want the overall `Checker` job to be considered as passed and allow the PR to merge. It is the same job after all, why should I care which trigger caused it to run (unless I'm debugging etc.)?

Am I using GitHub wrong?

I tried setting the `name` field on the job explicitly but it did not stop GitHub from appending the event to my job names. I also tried the `run-name` field but it did not change this behaviour.

Comment: GitHub has confirmed there is nothing that can be done. They are calling it an "implementation detail" on their end, but agreed something should be done to enable my use case (just not clear what, and I certainly consider it a bug since the same behaviour could be achieved via github expression syntax in the job name if I wanted this "detail"). I will post a more complete answer once I get to the bottom of my support ticket.